# Cannot connect to Postgres DB via psql cmd

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I issued the command:

```
psql -h localhost -U ruanpc
```

The console fails to connect to localhost postgres db and display:

```
psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility
```

My postgres and psql versions are:

```
ruanpc@slave-40:~$ postgres  --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11devel
ruanpc@slave-40:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11devel
```

Any one knows how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure if asking about development version of PostgreSQL is appropriate for SO. I would rather try their mailing lists. One tip I could give is to make sure you have latest dev libpq installed __and__ your build is linking to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I forget to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to Postgres shared library!

Easy fix for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your `psql` loads a libpq with version 9.5 or older. Make sure to use the same version of libpq as the `psql` version.